# Can't change file permissions with chmod in mounted devices

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, file-permissions, fstab

So, I wanted to share my Media via ftp by creating a symbolic link in the home directory of a ftpuser, to my HDD's partition 'Fun Drive'. What I wanted was that the ftpuser couldn't write to the Media directory, So I decided to give 775 permission to files. But when I do this by executing the following command

`chmod -R 755 /mnt/Fun_Drive`

and even after executing the above command. the permissions are still 777

I think this has probably something to do with the options in `/etc/fstab` file which mounts the partition when the system starts.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `something to do with the /etc/fstab file` why? what's in it?

Comment: @JaromandaX I thought there had been something to do with the options with which I mounted the filesystem.

Comment: could be - we can't see the file you think *may* be the problem - perhaps I was unclear ... can you show (**in the question**) the file you think may be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your HDD is currently formatted with a filesystem that does not support storing Unix style permissions. In particular, FAT and exFAT have *no* concept of permissions at all – whatever you set via mount options (e.g. `fmask=` in your fstab) is what you will see for all files, with the Linux FAT driver just pretending that those are the permissions.

So with FAT/exFAT you cannot customize permissions at file or directory level, only set them for the entire mount at once.

(NTFS *may* or may not be able to store such permissions. If you are using the "ntfs-3g" driver, it can't store them directly but can do a best-effort translation to native NTFS ACLs… which mostly works but needs manual setup.

Without this feature enabled, ntfs-3g behaves like FAT above and has fmask/dmask mount options.

For NTFS-formatted partitions I recommend switching to the newer "ntfs3" driver, which *does* support storing Unix permissions in WSL attributes.)